# Document.querySelector() returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, class, puppeteer, queryselector

I'm making a webscraping program in puppeteer which is supposed to collect text from a website.
I made this class in order to collect text from "#identifierId > option:nth-child(1)" and to store it as an object property, but it returns an undefined value: what am I missing?

```
async getText () {

   await this.page.waitForSelector('#identifierId> option:nth-child(1)');

   this.findText = await this.page.evaluate(() => {
        this.text = this.document.querySelector('#identifierId> option:nth-child(1)').innerText 
        return this.text
   })

   this.ArrayObject[0].text = this.findText.text

}
```

Comment: Change this line - this.ArrayObject[0].text = this.findText.text to this.ArrayObject[0].text = this.findText   - You should also improve your question and provide a bit more information for us to go on :)

Comment: Well, it worked! thanks

Comment: Your welcome, I'll post it as an answer with a little explanation so you know what to look for in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
async getText () {

   await this.page.waitForSelector('#identifierId> option:nth-child(1)');

   this.findText = await this.page.evaluate(() => {
        this.text = this.document.querySelector('#identifierId> option:nth-child(1)').innerText 
        return this.text
   })

   this.ArrayObject[0].text = this.findText

}
```

**Explanation -**
Basically, within your this.findText function, your actually already returning **this.text**, that means this.findText is actually already the value you're attempting to set this.ArrayObject[0].text to.